# Remove Text from below of the BarCode in ASP.NET(C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode

I am generating the barcode generation of barcode is working fine barcode also  read it perfectly.followin is the code for barcode generation:

```
private void GenerateBarCode(string codeInfo)
{
    //Settings for the Image
    string TypeFaceName = "IDAutomationHC39M";
    string imageLocation = Server.MapPath("2010.png");
    //The format of the image file
    ImageFormat format = ImageFormat.Png;
    //path of unique file name    
    string path = "D://MyProjects//RepeaterPaging//images//vijendra.png";
    //REFERENCING A FONT 
    PrivateFontCollection fnts = new PrivateFontCollection();
    fnts.AddFontFile("IDAutomationHC39M.ttf");
    FontFamily fntfam = new FontFamily(TypeFaceName);
    Font fnt = new Font(fntfam, 13);
    fnts.AddFontFile("Arial.ttf");
    FontFamily fntfam2 = new FontFamily("Arial", fnts);
    //DRAWING THE IMAGE  
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(960, 386);           //Canvas size
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    Bitmap orignBitmap = new Bitmap(imageLocation);
    g.Clear(Color.Transparent); //Background color
    SizeF bc = g.MeasureString(codeInfo, fnt);
    Brush br = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    g.DrawImage(orignBitmap, 10, 8);
    g.DrawString(codeInfo, fnt, br, 585, 170); //Drawing the Image
    g.TextRenderingHint= 
    bmp.Save(path, format); //Saving the Image file
    bmp.Dispose(); //Releasing all resources (Image file) 
    Response.Clear();
}
```

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/0e033f305b.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/0e033f305b.png)

Now I want to remove the text which is below of the barcode.
how can I do this?.

Comment: What does the output of that code look like?

Comment: @Tomas: My Barcode will without the number(*50036*)

Comment: What is the `orignBitmap` used for? Isn't the text coming from this image? Also in your code you are declaring the `Arial` font family which is never used.

Comment: @Darin - The barcode is a font, he'll need to draw a white rectangle hiding the numbers after drawing the barcode.

Comment: @Nick, just because barcode is a font when you `DrawString` instead of writing a human readable text it will draw bars. That's why I wonder where's this text coming from.

Comment: @Darin: orignBitmap is to draw the barcode on the exiting image on the specific location

Comment: @Nick Craver: You got there before me :) You should convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: Just a side note: you really should dispose the GDI+ objects suc as PrivateFontCollection. Omitting this can lead to the nuisance of strange hangs. Using "using" is a good way to do this.

Comment: @Darin - To clarify, the font is the bars **and** the text: http://www.fonts4free.net/idautomationhc39m-font.html

Comment: @Nick, thanks I get it now, the text is rendered as part of the font.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better alternative might be to just use a font that doesn't have the text in the first place:

Try something like:  [Free Barcode Font - Code 39](http://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/)

Comment: +1 for suggesting an alternative solution rather than just trying to fix the problem.

Comment: @Nick: Try to implement Barcode in alternative way is not answer of my question

Comment: @Vijjendra - I'm confused at to why you'd want a more difficult route?  My solution is download a **free** font file, pop it in and be done.  You'd rather render in your original font, draw rectangles over or calculate font sizes and strip the image down?  I've never seen someone choose the far more difficult/complicated route to the same solution, so I'm very puzzled by your comment.

Comment: @Vijjendra: Nick's answer is a valid solution as it only changes the font in use and is much simpler than having to correctly modify the bitmap after rendering the text. I'm interested to know why don't you like his answer?

Answer (score 10):

You can set `Font = null;` to remove text below barcode.

```
Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
code128.CodeType = Barcode.CODE128;
code128.Code = "123456789";
code128.Font = null;
```

Comment: This is the correct and working answer! I tried to set the Font and set the AltText to String.Empty. It got rid of the text but left the space after the barcode image. Setting the Font to null completely got rid of the alt. text and space.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! Took me half the day to find your answer :|. In VB.NET, use: code128.Font = Nothing

Comment: LIFE SAVER!!!  The documentation for iText never mentions anything like this.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the barcode using a font and the charcters under the bars are part of that font.

The only way to remove them would be to modify the bitmap (or crop it) after rendering the text; which requires knowing how big the final barcode is. Not impossible to do but a pain.