# How to remove text below the barcode image?

Tags: c#, barcode, zxing

I am using ZXing.NET to generate barcodes. I want to generate an image without the text below it. I am using the following code:

```
var content = "AAA";
var writer = new BarcodeWriter
{
    Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_39,
    Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
    {
        Height = 80,
        Width = 100,
        Margin = 1
    }
};
var bitmap = writer.Write(content);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244225/remove-text-from-below-of-the-barcode-in-asp-netc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`EncodingOptions` has `PureBarcode` as a boolean option. Setting it to `true` should ommit the text. You can check all options [in the source](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/blob/master/Source/lib/common/EncodingOptions.cs).

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. Now I am having trouble on the size of the barcode. It seems the longer the text, the longer the width of the barcode. And can't seem to adjust it. Anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: is this option also available for zxing java also?
I need to add text below barcode but not able to find any example in java.